# Running a script at start up in a specific directory

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a script that runs at boot and starts several applications in a particular sequence.

```
#!/bin/sh
...
APP1=/home/master/app1/App/app1
APP2=/home/master/app2/App/app2
...
case "$1" in
    start)
        echo echo "Starting App1\n"
        exec sudo -u master $APP1 >>/var/log/app1.log 2>&1 &
        sleep 5s
        echo echo "Starting App2\n"
        exec sudo -u master $APP2 >>/var/log/app2.log 2>&1 &
        ;;
...
```

However in the log files I notice that the applications are failing to open their respective ini files, but works fine when I run the applications manually.

How do I get the different applications to run at start up in their respective directories?

Comment: where are the ini files stored?

Comment: They are in the directories the executables are in.

Answer (score 0):

Your App is started in the directory in which "you are" in this moment.

Add a  line before you start the App: `cd <according path>`

This should solve it

Comment: I am pretty sure I tried this before and it failed to work but it now seems to work.  I have noticed that there are two instances of each application listed in top. So for app1 I see `sudo -u master /home/master/app1/App/app1` and `/home/master/app1/App/App1` though the latter has fractions of a second processing time compared to the former.